# Cordova plugin to detect Oculus Gear VR controls and taps

Tags: cordova, three.js, webgl, stereo-3d, virtual-reality

I am developing a Cordova application, which uses webgl, THREE.js to be more precise, to display 3D content. I implemented the stereoscopic rendering for Google Cardboard, which is working brilliantly, however, now I want to make another step and make my application available for the new Gear VR. My question would be: is there any way of detecting the Gear VR's side controls from Cordova? Is it magnetic, so that I could measure the magnetic flux around the phone and when it changes I could act upon it?

Thank you in advance,
any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually working on that and I think close to the solution but, for now I have to when 'no too technical ways to do it'. The first one (I haven't tested it yet because I'm continuously switching carboard/gearvr sol.) is here: [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/GearVR/comments/3c061s/cardboard_on_gear_vr_for_s6_easy_nonroot_solution/)

The second one (which I'm using now) is, take a look at this link: [link](http://how-tosolve.com/tube/r9Ub5IW1F0s/top-5-hidden-features-on-the-original-samsung-gear-vr) see 9:05

Yes, I know, it's not too 'professional' but it works! Anyway don't turn your head too fast.

Comment: Let me take a look at these two suggestions, thanks for commenting! I think the best solution would be to just publish the app in the Oculus VR Store, but even though this would solve the problem of accessing my app from within the VR set, reading back the controls is still a big ask.